# What sections of the final chapter are real, and the ones that are flashbacks/dream sequences?

Tags: girl-may-kill

The final chapter of Girl May Kill is very confusing.

There is a lot of dream sequences / flashbacks mingled with the real story, and I am having a hard time separating them.

The pages with a black background are not real. But what happened?

> Did she really kill Gohongi? If she killed him, what did it accomplish?

And later on

> If Gohongi is dead, is she only dreaming of how it would go if he was alive (when she is grown up and says "I am glad you waited for me to grow up") when she eventually grow up?

Comment: When I get back home and can access CR I will add page references. In the meantime if anyone feels inclined to do so, please do.